# Discontinuities of $f(x)=\begin{cases}|x^2-1| & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational} \\0 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x^2-1| & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational} \\0 & \text{if } x \text{ is rational}\end{cases}$

what can we say about the number of points of continuity of the function $f$?

$f$ is discontinuous at irrationals,I think it is only continuous at $x$=$0$ but I am not sure about that.

Comment: At $x = 0$, your function can take on $0$ or $1$. So it is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is discontinuous at all points except $x=\pm 1$. In the vicinity of $\pm 1$, the value is $0$ or $0^+$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $1.$ There are $\infty$ rational numbers in the neighbourhood of any irrational number and vice versa

$2$. When does $|x^2-1|$ become equal to $0$?